# Closed forms for $\sum^{n-1}_{r=1} (n-r) \sin \left(\frac{2\pi r}{n} \right)$ and $\sum^{n-1}_{r=1} (n-r) \omega^r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Question: Suppose that $\omega$ is a non-real $n$th root of unity, where $n \geq 3$. Prove that:

(i) $\sum^{n-1}_{r=1} (n-r) \cos \left(\frac{2r \pi}{n} \right)=-\frac{n}{2}$

(ii) $\sum^{n-1}_{r=1} (n-r) \sin \left(\frac{2r \pi}{n} \right)=\frac{n}{2} \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{n} \right)$

(iii) $\sum^{n-1}_{r=1} (n-r) \omega^r=\frac{n\omega}{1-\omega}$

I managed to prove (i) by considering $(n-r) \cos \left(\frac{2r \pi}{n} \right)$ for $n=n$ and $n=n-r$ then adding the two results (since $\cos(2\pi-\theta)=\cos \theta$), then summing $\cos \left(\frac{2r \pi}{n} \right)$ by using sum-to-product to create a telescoping series.

However, I cannot use the same logic for (i), and so I'm a bit stuck. Because the required result involves $\frac{\pi}{n}$, I was thinking to use the formula $\sin 2\theta=2\sin \theta \cos \theta$, which yields $$\sum^{n-1}_{r=1} (n-r) \sin \left(\frac{2r \pi}{n} \right)=2\sum^{n-1}_{r=1} (n-r) \sin \left(\frac{r\pi}{n} \right) \cos \left(\frac{r\pi}{n} \right)$$ But that's about the limit of my ideas.

Comment: Hint: you don't need to brute force the first two, they are deducible from the last one. For the last one, separate your sum! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will denote $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ your sums in order.

Note that $S_1 = \Re (S_3)$ and $S_2 = \Im(S_3)$, so we'll compute $S_3$ (this is cool since it is the easiest if you know the trick).
$$S_3 = \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} (n-r)w^r  = w\left(n \sum_{r=0}^{n-2} w^r - \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} r w^{r-1} \right) = w\left(n\frac{1-w^{n-1}}{1-w} + \frac{d}{dz} \left(\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} z^{r} \right)(w) \right)$$
so
$$S_3 =  n\frac{w-1}{1-w} + w\frac{d}{dz} \left(\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}\right)(w) = n\frac{w-1}{1-w} + w\left( \frac{1-w^n}{(1-w)^2} - n \frac{w^{n-1}}{1-w} \right) = n\left(\frac{w-1}{1-w} + \frac{1}{1-w}\right) = \frac{nw}{1-w}$$

From that you get
$$S_3 = n\frac{w-1}{|1-w|^2} $$
but if $w = e^{2ik\pi/n}$, $k \neq 0 \mod n$ and $k + n/2 \neq 0 \mod n$,
$$w-1 =2 i e^{i k \pi/n} \sin(k\pi/n) $$
so

- $|1-w| = 2 \sin(k\pi/n)$
- $\Re(w-1) = -2\sin^2(k\pi/n)$
- $\Im(w-1) = 2 \cos(ik\pi/n)\sin(ik\pi/n)$

Which gives us
$$S_1 = n\frac{-2\sin^2(k\pi/n)}{4\sin^2(k\pi/n)} = -\frac{n}{2}$$
$$S_2 = n\frac{2 \cos(ik\pi/n)\sin(ik\pi/n)}{4\sin^2(k\pi/n)} = \frac{n}{2} \cot (k\pi/n)$$
but I don't have your result exactly and Wolfram agrees with me

Little edit: I did not see that $S_2$ was for $k=1$, this solves the problem directly :)